# CSS Animation not displaying

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to create a CSS animation that displays my cloud image and then in a four second duration the cloud moves to the left until it hits the end point. For whatever reason, I am not getting anything to display in my attempt.

Does anyone see anything that could be causing this not to display?

```css
#cloud-container {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
#cloud-animation {
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: cloud;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  animation-name: cloud;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes cloud {
  0% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/cloud.JPG");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    left: 30%;
    top: 0px;
  }
  1000% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/cloud.JPG");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    left: 10%;
    top: 0px;
  }
} 
@-webkit-keyframes cloud {
  0% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/cloud.JPG");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    left: 30%;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/cloud.JPG");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    left: 10%;
    top: 0px;
  }
} 
}
```

```html
<div id="cloud-container">
  <div id="cloud-animation"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the links of the background rules give 404

Comment: I have no idea how a 404 is being given. It opens up in my file manager.

Comment: @silviagreen I figured out the path problem. I had to capitalize the JPG. I also corrected the 1000% error. For some reason though, the photo just gets smaller and fades out. Do you see any reason why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works but you have two mistakes:

1. The images are missing (404 error)
2. You have the 1000% not the 100% in the second keyframe

You can test it works with a border:

```css
#cloud-container {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
#cloud-animation {
  background-image: url("http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: cloud;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  animation-name: cloud;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes cloud {
  0% {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    left: 30%;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    left: 10%;
    top: 0px;
  }
} 
@-webkit-keyframes cloud {
  0% {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    left: 30%;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    left: 10%;
    top: 0px;
  }
} 
}
```

```html
<div id="cloud-container">
  <div id="cloud-animation"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I figured out the path problem. I had to capitalize the JPG. I also corrected the 1000% error. For some reason though, the photo just gets smaller and fades out. Do you see any reason why?

Comment: I modeled this more like yours and took out the height from each keyframe. Worked great. Thanks!@

Comment: Are you the same @Becky of the problem with queue()? Nice to see you again :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is the animation you want, then I simply added the background-image rule to the #cloud-animation div.

```css
#cloud-container {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
#cloud-animation {
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
     background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/cloud.JPG");
/*ADD HERE THE background too*/
  -webkit-animation-name: cloud;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  animation-name: cloud;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes cloud {
  0% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/cloud.JPG");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    left: 30%;
    top: 0px;
  }
  1000% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/cloud.JPG");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    left: 10%;
    top: 0px;
  }
} 
@-webkit-keyframes cloud {
  0% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/cloud.JPG");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    left: 30%;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/cloud.JPG");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    left: 10%;
    top: 0px;
  }
} 
}
```

```html
<div id="cloud-container">
  <div id="cloud-animation"></div>
</div>
```